# Bound Callable Reference Not Working With Reactor Subscribe

Tags: kotlin

Since 1.1, Kotlin has had *bound callable references*. As I am on 1.1.3, I think I should be able to use the following to access the `add` method :

```
val elements = mutableListOf<Int>()

Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4)
    .log()
    .subscribe(elements::add)
```

However, this throws an error:

[image: elements::add error]

I'm not sure what that error means in this specific instance. I can use `.subscribe({ elements.add(it) })` with no issue, but shouldn't I be able to use the `elements::add` version?

Comment: *n.b.*: This is an issue with the return type of the lambda not being unit. Return type inference is slated to be changed in 1.2 so that the code in this example would work correctly. See: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11723

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin Function Reference Expression is not like as java Method Reference Expression. the return type `Any` is not compatible with the return type `Unit`.

the error comes from the return type (*Boolean*) of the `MutableList#add(Int)` method is not compatible with the parameter parameter type *`(Int)->Unit`* of the `subscribe` method.
so you can only using lambda expression this way.

you can using `list::add` in somewhere when  both the parameter types and return type are compatible with the function. for example:

```
val add1:(Int) -> Boolean = list::add; // MutableList.add(Int);
val add2:(Int,Int) -> Unit = list::add; // MutableList.add(Int,Int);
```

Comment: Just wanted to note that I discovered https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11723 and 1.2 will likely allow for coercing lambdas to Unit. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 2):

To rephrase and elaborate on the other answer: the problem is that a `Consumer` is expected, which takes an element and returns nothing in its single method. The corresponding function type for this in Kotlin would be `(T) -> Unit`.

The [`add`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/add.html) method described in the `MutableList` interface however has the type `(T) -> Boolean`: it returns true if the element was successfully added (this is to support implementations of the interface that can't contain duplicates).

A possible solution to this is to add an extension method that adds an element to a `MutableList` without returning anything:

```
fun <T> MutableList<T>.addItem(element: T): Unit {
    this.add(element)
}
```

You can then use a bound callable reference to this extension, just like other `MutableList` methods:

```
Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4)
        .log()
        .subscribe(elements::addItem)
```

Comment: Just wanted to note that I discovered https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11723 and 1.2 will likely allow for coercing lambdas to Unit. Thanks for the information!

Comment: Cool, this would be a nice little addition to the language, and it doesn't seem to conflict with any existing use cases on first glance.